# How to handle dynamic struct instantiation?

Tags: oop, generics, rust

I have many structs that implement a trait, and I need a function that returns an instance of one of this structs depending on runtime conditions. I am also having trouble to figure out the signature for the `new()` method, but I guess these two are related.

**Struct def example**

```rust
trait Example {
    fn new<T>() -> T where T: Example;

    fn do_something(&self) {
        //something to do
    }
}

struct Ex1 {
    some_attr: String
}

struct Ex2 {
    some_attr: String
}

impl Example for Ex1 {
    fn new<T>() -> T where T: Example {
        Ex1{ some_attr: "".to_string() }
    }
}

impl Example for Ex2 {
    fn new<T>() -> T where T: Example {
        Ex2{ some_attr: "".to_string() }
    }
}
```

**Main/function example**

```rust
fn conditionally_generate_struct() -> Box<dyn Example> {
    let condition = true;
    return if condition {
        Ex1::new()
    } else {
        Ex2::new()
    }
}

let example = conditionally_generate_struct();
example.do_something();
```

When looking into it I've found some ways like using `Box` or `T` but I don't fully understand how to use them. To be honest, I don't even know how to categorize this problem. Is it a problem solved by the concept of generics?

What is the right way to do it in Rust? And what concept am I missing?

**Some clarification**

*Trait and Struct*

I've put the new method in the trait because I want to already fill some attributes (there are many of them) when the struct is instantiated and each struct has different values but it's a fixed value, that sounded the better way to do it. Trying to avoid to set the same values each time I instantiate the struct.

```rust
impl Example for Ex1 { 
    fn new() -> Self { 
        Ex1{ name: "Example1".to_string() }
    } 
}

impl Example for Ex2 { 
    fn new() -> Self { 
        Ex2{ name: "Example2".to_string() }
    } 
}
```

*Box and function*

I don't necessarily want to return a `Box` from the function, I want to return one of the structs that implements the `Example` trait so I can use then on the callsite, `Box` was the way I've found to do it, assuming this is the right way I've made this modifications:

```rust
fn conditionally_generate_struct() -> Box<dyn Example> {
    let condition = true;
    return if condition {
        Box::new(Ex1{ some_attr: "".to_string() })
    } else {
        Box::new(Ex2{ some_attr: "".to_string() })
    }
}
```

**Errors and warnings**

*Error*

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Example` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/example.rs:31:43
   |
31 | fn conditionally_generate_struct() -> Box<dyn Example> {
   |                                           ^^^^^^^ `Example` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/example.rs:10:8
   |
9  | pub trait Example {
   |           ------- this trait cannot be made into an object...
10 |     fn new() -> Self;
   |        ^^^ ...because associated function `new` has no `self` parameter
          +++++
```

Comment: You don't need explicit `<T>`: it's already present per-struct as `Self`

Comment: If you want to return a box (which is a sensible way to do it), you need to make a box. Also, you need to implement the methods of the trait.

Comment: Please show your errors and the specific problem you want to solve. Right now this lacks some crucial details and is a bit opinion based

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've made some clarifications on the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
trait Example {
    fn new<T>() -> T where T: Example;
    // ...
}
```

You (almost certainly) don't want this: this would mean that any type that implements the trait `Example` can be asked at the callsite to return any other type that also implements `Example`. For example:

```
struct Foo; impl Example for Foo { ... }
struct Bar; impl Example for Bar { ... }

// callsite
let foo = Foo;
let bar: Bar = foo.new::<Bar>();
```

That would be very strange. So *in general*, this kind of method is where you want to use [`Self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#defining-methods), a type which stands for "the current type", i.e. the type written at the top of the `impl` block.

```
trait Example {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

struct Foo;
impl Example for Foo {
    fn new() -> Self { Foo }
}
struct Bar;
impl Example for Bar {
    fn new() -> Self { Bar }
}
```

In this specific case, however, `new` seems completely unnecessary, unless there is something in your codebase that you haven't explained in the OP. This is because there is no actual shared behaviour: it's just construction of the struct. Why call `<Foo as Example>::new()` when you can simply call `Foo::new()` or even directly construct `Foo { .. }`? The result will be the same.

For the second part of your question:

```rust
fn conditionally_generate_struct() -> Box<dyn Example> {
    let condition = true;
    if condition {
        Box::new(Ex1 { .. })
    } else {
        Box::new(Ex2 { .. })
    }
}

let example = conditionally_generate_struct();
example.do_something();
```

To return a `Box`, you need to actually construct a `Box`. There is no automatic conversion from structs implementing a trait into a boxed trait object, as this could be a footgun.

Also note, again, that the structs are constructed directly rather than calling the unnecessary trait method.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer, I've made some clarifications of the goal and errors that are popping to me right now.

Comment: @EduardoFellipe Re: the `new` function: yes, you can still have a `new` function to reduce duplication, but you should put it into `impl Ex1 { ... }` instead of `impl Example for Ex1`. If you remove the `new` method from the trait, you will also get rid of the "trait is not object safe" error.

Comment: worked!, thanks, for some reason in my mind I could only `impl` a struct once, I will look deeper into the `Box` type and the "trait is not object safe" error.